# Included in or included on

Tags: grammar, commas

Which of the following serene is correct?

Please note:  the North stores are included in the report. We will update te report once the data is available( do I need a commas after "in the report"? )

Or

Please note:  the North stores are included on the report. We will update te report once the data is available

Answer (score 3):

"in the report"

The comma would be incorrect.

Also, "the" not "te"

"sentence" not "serene"